# Operator ":=" not allowed in this context

Tags: python, syntax-error

my code:

```py
print(" ".join([(a[i] if (ord(a[i]) - 97 % 2) == 0 else a[i].upper()) for i in range(len(a := input()))].sort(reverse=True)))
```

when I run that code, I get this error:

```
Operator ":=" not allowed in this context
```

I want to write the following code in one line:

```py
input_string = str(input())
array = []
for i in range(len(input_string)):
    if (ord(input_string[i]) - 97) % 2 == 0:
        array.append(input_string[i])
    else:
        array.append(input_string[i].upper())
array.sort(reverse=True)
answer = ' '.join(array)
print(answer)
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to cram it into a single line?  The longer version should be the preferred method.

Comment: Taking data from the standard input during a list comprehension can be made to work but it's very bad practice. And, as @Chris has asked, why all in one line? Are you deliberately trying to obfuscate your code? Also, *input()* returns a string so no need to call *str()*

Comment: the "walrus operator" (`:=`) is pretty new to the python. are you using a current version of python?

Comment: Just directly iterate over the input. There is no need to have the index.

Comment: @PaulH OP must be running 3.8+ otherwise that error would not have occurred. In earlier versions it would have been a syntax error. Walrus operator is not available in all contexts

Comment: @PaulH Assignment is not allowed in the innermost comprehension iterable expression. ["named expressions are disallowed entirely as part of comprehension iterable expressions"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target)

Comment: You are trying to `join` a `None`... You have `' '.join([...].sort())`. `sort` returns `None`...

Comment: And no need for the walrus operator at all as you don't need to iterate over indices at all... `" ".join(sorted([(c if (ord(c) - 97 % 2) == 0 else c.upper()) for c in input()], reverse=True))`

Comment: ``print(" ".join(sorted([(i if (ord(i) - 97) % 2 == 0 else i.upper()) for i in input()], reverse=True)))`` Should do. Note that the ``%2`` was wrong and you cannot sort the list inplace.

Comment: @Chrisi t's a question. I most write it in one line

Comment: @PaulH yes. I have python 3.10

Answer (score 1):

it's solved. Thank's @MisterMiyagi and @Tomerikoo

code:

```
print(" ".join(sorted([(c if (ord(c) - 97) % 2 == 0 else c.upper()) for c in input()], reverse=True)))
```